# How to get directions between two locations in the form of text in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, maps, driving-directions, map-directions

I remember there is an Google API which tooks either lat,long or from&to address, if we load that url on webview, it used to show the directions between two points in the form of Text. Can any one provide me the API to get text based directions. I don't want to draw the line on Maps, want to show the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.776142, -122.424774) addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

MKMapItem *srcMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:source];
[srcMapItem setName:@""];

MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.73787, -122.373962) addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

MKMapItem *distMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:destination];
[distMapItem setName:@""];

MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
[request setSource:srcMapItem];
[request setDestination:distMapItem];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny];

MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];

[direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"response = %@",response);
    NSArray *arrRoutes = [response routes];
    [arrRoutes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        MKRoute *rout = obj;

        MKPolyline *line = [rout polyline];
        [mapview addOverlay:line];
        NSLog(@"Rout Name : %@",rout.name);
        NSLog(@"Total Distance (in Meters) :%f",rout.distance);

        NSArray *steps = [rout steps];

        NSLog(@"Total Steps : %lu",(unsigned long)[steps count]);
        NSMutableArray *stepsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [steps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"Rout Instruction : %@",[obj instructions]);
            NSLog(@"Rout Distance : %f",[obj distance]);
            [stepsArray addObject:[obj instructions]];
        }];

        [self myShowDirections:response];
        self.steps.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stepsArray];
```

You can use this and get what you want.